# Add google sheet drawing to unprotected range?

Tags: google-sheets

My objective is to use the protected features to lock many Google sheets, with some unprotected ranges. Works really great, however my problem is that drawings are also protected now - not something I intended.

Can I somehow add a drawing to the unprotected ranges - or is there another way where I can allow the users of the spreadsheet to edit comments (I use a drawing for a text-box)?

Comment: In the current stage, the drawing on Spreadsheet can be managed with Google Apps Script. How about this? But unfortunately, I cannot image your current situation from your question. I apologize for this. And, I cannot understand about `is there another way where I can allow the users of the spreadsheet to edit comments (I use a drawing for a text-box)?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: So, just to make sure I understood right, you have a [protected sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and in that sheet you would like to add the exception of the drawings (i.e, people can edit these drawings but nothing else in the sheet) am I right?

Comment: Yes Mateo - correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue: to be able to have a [protected sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) where everything apart from drawings is editable.

In the sheet you want to protect, instead of selecting the whole sheet to protect you can instead protect a range selecting the range that contains all your sheet (i.e, in the default sheet this would be from `A1:Z1000`. This will effectively protect your sheet while allowing you to insert and/or **edit drawings**.

Comment: Will this allow for expected ranges as well?

Comment: What do you mean by ***expected ranges***?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. I meant "unprotectedRanges", as described here under the section "ProtectedRange": https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#ProtectedRange

Comment: Yes, but just to make sure and clarify, do you have a whole sheet or just some ranges protected in that sheet? The thing is, if you protect the sheet itself, it will not let you edit anything in it including drawings. However, if instead of protecting the whole sheet directly you protect **all the cells** instead, it will effectively let you edit the drawings (as they are not assigned to any cell but to a sheet).

Comment: I understand that point. But my follow up question is then: If I protect all ranges with `A1:Z1000`, can I then add a unproctedRange, let's say `A1:A10`?

Comment: Yes, of course, as soon as you don't protect the whole sheet (and just protect/unprotect ranges) you should be able to edit drawings. :D